# Set first annotation in annotations

Tags: ios, swift2, mapkit, mapkitannotation

OK,
I have an array of pubs:

```
var pubs = [Pub(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.2282385, longitude: 76.855085)),
    Pub(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.2345965, longitude: 76.8907758)).
```

and I add annotations to my map:

```
mapView.addAnnotations(pubs).
```

Then I select first annotation this way:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.annotations.first!, animated: true)
```

But now it shows first selected annotations, then second.

Question:
How to set the needed annotation first in annotations?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "But now it shows first selected annotations, then second." ?

Comment: I have tableView, where are 2 pubs. When I select first, it has to show first pub selected and second pub not selected. And when I select second, it has to show second pub selected and first pub not selected. (sorry for my english). But when I tap on first pub, it shows sometimes first pub, sometimes second.

Comment: and what happens when you do selectAnnotation ? it should do exactly as you want

Comment: When I do selectAnnotation, it selects pub randomly.

Comment: mapView might re-arrange the array of the Pubs, try selecting it from the TableView-s array mapView.selectAnnotation(tableView.annotations.first!, animated: true)

Comment: in what method? In prepareForSegue or didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: did Select Row at Index Path , if the MapView is in the different ViewController, then pass the selected Pub or selected indexPath in a different property/variable and select it after mapView is shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95963/discussion-between-aaisataev-and-ogres).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Howe said @ogres: `mapView` might re-arrange the array of the `Pubs`, so i had to select it from the `TableView`-s array `mapView.selectAnnotation(tableView.annotations.first!, animated: true)`